# Meteor.js CircleCI integration fails on linting

Tags: testing, meteor, circleci

I'm trying to get CircleCI to run tests that are failing linting, however it fails on something particular to the way Meteor works, by running on both the server and the client.  Some code should only run when on the server or the client.  Lint fails when you try to do an import inside of any other block:

```
...
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { _ } from 'meteor/underscore';
import { DDP } from 'meteor/ddp-client';

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  import './server/publications.coffee';
...
```

with the following error:

```
/home/ubuntu/todos/imports/api/lists/lists.tests.js
  16:3  error  Parsing error: 'import' and 'export' may only appear at the top level
```

Obviously this isn't in line with Meteor's way of doing this, since this is in the meteor/todo app, and works just fine.

How do you bypass the CircleCI linting check, or change this to a warn item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eslint parser does not accept the Meteor nested import syntax, since the ES6 spec does not allow it either. See details [here](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/6472). There are two options get around this: either switch to the [babel-eslint](https://github.com/babel/babel-eslint) parser which supports this syntax with the `allowImportExportEverywhere` option. You need to modify your package.json like this:

```json
"devDependencies": {
  ...
  "babel-eslint": "^5.0.4"
},
"eslintConfig": {
  "parser": "babel-eslint",
  "parserOptions": {
    "sourceType": "module",
    "allowImportExportEverywhere": false
  },
}
...
```

Alternatively you can simply use `require` to conditionally include files the old-fashioned way:

```js
if (Meteor.isServer) {
  require('./server/publications.coffee'); // eslint-disable-line global-require
}
```

Either of these options should make the lint pass on CircleCI. I also recommend [setting up linting in your editor](https://guide.meteor.com/code-style.html#eslint-editor) if you plan on using it in CircleCI.